# Usage of Ernst as noun vs adjective in german

Tags: adjective, noun

In English, I would say:

> You can not be serious!

But, in German, one could either say:

> Du kannst es nicht ernst meinen (ernst as adjective)

or,

> Das kann doch nicht dein Ernst sein. (ernst as noun)

When I check [reverso](https://context.reverso.net/translation/german-english/Ernst), it seems to me that the noun form of Ernst is used more often. Is this actually true? If so, when should it be appropriate to use the adjective form of Ernst?

Answer (score 3):

There are some fixed phrases as

> Jetzt mal im Ernst: …

> Das kann doch nicht dein Ernst sein!

> der Ernst des Lebens

> mit dem nötigen Ernst

Those four account for I think 90% of the uses of the noun *der Ernst*.

Use those phrases if they fit. And otherwise the adjective.

Comment: I'd consider most of these to be idiomatic, at least to some extent. The second sentence word for word in English is "That can't be your seriousness!" But the English phrase is "You can't be serious!"

Comment: Die 90% sind eine aus der Luft gegriffene Zahl. Niemand führt Protokoll über Häufigkeiten von Formulierungen; nicht für alltägliche Begriffe wie Ernst und ernst. Seine Sprache so zu wählen, wie es die meisten häufig tun ist auch keine sinnvolle Empfehlung. "Das meinst Du doch nicht ernst!" ist m.E. ebenso gängig wie Dein Satz 2. Außerdem gibt es viele Alternativen die weder Ernst, noch ernst enthalten, "mit der nötigen Sorgfalt/Aufmerksamkeit/Leidenschaft" (4), "Wirklich?/Echt jetzt?" (2) Wichtig ist, dass man verstanden wird und je nach Umständen können Formulierungen mehr oder weniger passen

Answer (score 2):

"ernst" (written non-capitalized, an *Adjektiv* or *Adverb*) means, as you noticed yourself, *serious*.

"Ernst" (capitalized, a *Nomen*) means *seriousness*.

You can use it interchangeably with a few modifications to the sentence, for instance:

> Ich sah sein ernstes Gesicht.
> <sub>I saw his serious(-looking) face.</sub>
> Ich sah den Ernst in seinem Gesicht.
> <sub>I saw the seriousness in his face.</sub>

Notice, that "ernst" (both the *Adjektiv* and the *Nomen*) not only means the opposite of "funny" but also "severe", "grave", "austere", etc.. For instance, there was an Austrian general who answered his emperor, asking for the situation on the front:

> Die Lage ist hoffnungslos, Sire, aber noch nicht ernst.
> <sub>The situation is hopeless but not grim.</sub>

This is the inversion of an idiom "ernst aber nicht hoffnungslos": (serious but) not all is lost (now).

Also notice, that "Ernst" is also a name ("Ernest"). All sorts of play on words exist like:

> Aus Spaß wurde Ernst und der ist heute 3 Jahre alt.
> <sub>Fun turned earnest(ness) and he is 3 years now.</sub>